# Rails structure.sql is invalid (foreign keys reference tables not yet created)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

We have had to switch from schema.rb to structure.sql, since we needed a VARBINARY field in MySQL with an index of a specified length on it, which schema.rb doesn't handle, but structure.sql does.

Unfortunately, we've now hit a bigger issue. The structure.sql file contains `CREATE TABLE` statements in alphabetical order. Our tables have foreign key constraints on them. The structure.sql file includes these key constraints, but references tables that don't get created until further down the file.

e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE attachments (
  id INT NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id INT,
  /* ... snip ... */
  CONSTRAINT attachments_user_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8;

/* ... snip ... */

CREATE TABLE users (
  id INT NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
  /* ... snip ... */
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8;
```

Is there a workaround for this? It seems so fundamentally broken for such a common DB schema design principle I can't even believe this is a thing. We're on Rails 3.2.12.

Answer (score 0):

Best I'm aware, there's no fix short of rewriting your SQL file to sort the create table statements in the correct order, or creating the foreign key constraints at the very end.

Consider changing whatever tool you used to create the dump file, too. Dump files should be able to run, and this one evidently doesn't...

Comment: This is just what Rails spits out when using `rake db:migrate`. When you then try to run the unit tests, it will use this file to generate a test schema... which explodes. Changing the tool is basically what I'm asking, since we (obviously) need to be able to run `rake db:migrate`, but that does the wrong thing. I'm informed by somebody else that this is fixed in Rails 4.0, so we may upgrade and just move on ;)

Comment: I'd suggest filing a bug in Rails if it's still occurring in the latest version. :|